# Как на python на QWebEngineView заблокировать возможность кликать по окну и скролить?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Интересует как на QWebEngineView возможно заблокировать возможность кликать по окну и прокручивать страницу. А так же через некоторое время чтобы такая возможность появлялась, то есть включить обратно доступ к окну. Или возможно это можно было сделать наложив сверху прозрачный слой? Если да, то как это сделать? Буду признателен за пример кода, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотел сначала предложить вам сложные варианты (1. виджет поверх QWebEngineView 2. перехват событий клика и скролла), но вспомнил о простом `setEnabled`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

app = QApplication([])

mw = QWebEngineView()
mw.load(QUrl("https://ru.stackoverflow.com"))
mw.setEnabled(False)
mw.show()

QTimer.singleShot(5000, lambda: mw.setEnabled(True))

app.exec()
```

Через 5 секунд после запуска окно снова станет активным и будет обрабатывать клики и скролл

Answer (score 1):

Я вам отвечу на вопрос `Или возможно это можно было сделать наложив сверху прозрачный слой?`
Это немного сложнее чем в предыдущем ответе, но это надо попробовать :)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QSplashScreen, QLabel,
                             QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, 
                             QPushButton, QGridLayout, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy  )
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer, pyqtSlot, Qt, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui  import QPixmap, QMovie
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


Stylesheet = """
#Custom_Widget {
    background: rgba(255, 200, 255, 100);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#closeButton {
    min-width: 36px;
    min-height: 36px;
    font-family: "Webdings";
    qproperty-text: "r";
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#closeButton:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    background: red;
}
"""


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setObjectName('Custom_Dialog')
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)

        self.initUi()

        # Добавить тень
        effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        effect.setBlurRadius(12)
        effect.setOffset(2, 2)
        effect.setColor(Qt.gray)        
        self.setGraphicsEffect(effect)

    def initUi(self):
        # Важно: этот widget используется в качестве фона и закругленных углов
        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setObjectName('Custom_Widget')
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)

        # Добавить пользовательский интерфейс в виджет
        layout = QGridLayout(self.widget)
        layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum), 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton(
            'r', self, clicked=self.accept, objectName='closeButton'), 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("<h1 style='color: red;'>Hello, World!</h1>"), 
                                 2, 0, 5, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)                           

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(800, 600) 


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        # Заставка        
        self.movie_screen = QLabel()
        self.movie_screen.setWindowFlags(  Qt.FramelessWindowHint  
                                         | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint  
                                         | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint
                                        )
        self.movie_screen.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.movie = QMovie("loading.gif")
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()
        self.movie_screen.adjustSize()        
        self.movie_screen.show()

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://doc.qt.io/qt-5"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.on_loadFinished)

    @pyqtSlot(bool)
    def on_loadFinished(self, ok):
        if not ok:
            return
        # Закрыли заставку
        self.movie_screen.close()

        # окно без границ, прозрачный слой
        self.dialog = Dialog()
        self.dialog.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("My Window")
    w.resize(640, 400) 
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подобная тема с накрыванием виджетов "стеклом" мне встречалась: http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_24835_0.html Причем, накрыть можно было любой виджет и это делалось без создания окна поверх него. В вашей реализации окно позади ведь можно двигать, если на него переключиться? То "стекло" еще в нескольких проектах после использовал: https://github.com/search?q=user%3Agil9red+SBGlass&type=Code Оно хоть и на с++ сделано, но легко переписывается на питон

Comment: @gil9red окно позади двигать не получится:
 во-первых dialog.exec_(), во-вторых размер 'стекла' больше 'окна позади'.

Comment: Ну да... модальный диалог не дает переключиться на главное окно. Я бы у диалога убрал флаг "поверх всех окон", т.к. он будучи модальным поверх главного окна будет

Comment: @gil9red оставил специально, вдруг кто-то задумает `exec` заменить на  `open`или `show` :)

Comment: Тот, кто так захочет сделать будет сам себе злым бурантино :D