# Как отобразить слой с текстом, поверх программы не в Full Screen Mode? Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, qt, pyqt5, поиск-библиотек

Есть программа запущенная в оконном режиме, на весь экран без бордюров, например какая то игра.
Необходимо вывести тест по верх этого окна. (Не в этом окне, а создать возможно свое окно прозрачное над окном игры или как то еще.)
Какими средствами это можно сделать из Python3?

Comment: Чужое окно программы и вы хотите в него вывести свою информацию?

Comment: @gil9red Поправил вопрос.

Comment: Попробуйте например `pyqt5`, а вот тут пример создания своего окна без рамок и с полупрозрачностью: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/0d88af83136ce7e7c1e48cce20a81e17e170a833/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt__frameless_window_with_part_transparent_body.py . Так же полупрозрачность можно через setWindowOpacity сделать: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop. В моем примере можно добавить в paintEvent рисование текста через painter.drawText, рисование рамки убрать, а тело окна либо вообще не рисовать (без drawRect), либо в цвет тела увеличить прозрачность

Comment: @gil9red да Qt5 я как раз и использую в приложении и как окна создавать знаю, а вот как его сделать прозрачным не знал. Ок. Остается еще вопрос, как обеспечить то чтобы окно было поверх игры?

Comment: @gil9red WindowStaysOnTopHint поможет? можно ли его совместить с FramelessWindowHint ?

Comment: Посмотрите может пригодится https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/994690/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-%D0%BD%D0%B0-qwebengineview-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE/994794#994794